# grepping text within a multi-column list with a provided string

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script to handle multiple uses for searching lists. Long story short, I am querying a DB and have a basic list such as this:

```
    sdc         10:0            KQJWBE11
    sdd         10:1            KSDJFBQK
    sde         10:2            13KN13DD
    sdf         10:3            123DJN1O
    sdg         10:4            213JBDKJ
    sdh         10:5            N2QQWMNE
    sdi         10:6            QKEWJDQJ
    sdj         10:7            QKWJEDWE
    sdk         20:0            QEDQWEDQ
    sdl         20:1            1234E13L
    sdm         20:2            KQNE2OUN
    sdn         20:3            QN2NK3JN
    sdo         20:4            23J23EN2
    sdp         20:5            2WBNEKNW
    sdq         20:6            QWEDKJNW
    sdr         20:7            QWEDQEDD
```

These exist in the variable "${TABLE_FORMAT}" and are formatted as just as above into a table.

```
#... other logic above this

 # Query via primary and secondary location. Example: DISK_ARG="10:1"

 elif [[ ${DISK_ARG} =~ ([[:digit:]]:[[:digit:]])+$ ]]; then
          DISK_ARG_PRIMARY=$(echo "${DISK_ARG}" | cut -d: -f1)
          DISK_ARG_SECONDARY=$(echo "${DISK_ARG}" | cut -d: -f2)
          echo -e "${HEADER}"
          echo -e "${TABLE_FORMAT}" | grep -Ei "($DISK_ARG_PRIMARY):($DISK_ARG_SECONDARY)"
       fi


 # Query secondary location. Example: DISK_ARG="5"

 elif [[ ${DISK_ARG} =~ ([[:digit:]])+$ ]]; then
          DISK_ARG_F2="$(echo "${F2}" | grep -Ei "([[:digit:]]):(${DISK_ARG})")"
          DISK_ARG_PRIMARY=$(echo "${DISK_ARG_F2}" | cut -d: -f1)
          DISK_ARG_SECONDARY=$(echo "${DISK_ARG_F2}" | cut -d: -f2)
          echo -e "${TABLE_FORMAT}" | grep -Ei "($DISK_ARG_PRIMARY):($DISK_ARG_SECONDARY)"
       fi

 else :

 fi
```

The offending line that doesn't work is in the second elif:

```
echo -e "${TABLE_FORMAT}" | grep -Ei "($DISK_ARG_PRIMARY):($DISK_ARG_SECONDARY)"

grep: Unmatched ( or \(
```

The current variables at this point are:

```
DISK_ARG_PRIMARY="10 20" 
DISK_ARG_SECONDARY="5 5"
```

I want the following rendered as output:

```
sdh         10:5            N2QQWMNE
sdp         20:5            2WBNEKNW
```

I'm not sure if this could be accomplished with building some type of array in grep or modifying the IFS somehow. I want the script to handle many inputs and look for matches off of the relevant fields.

Answer (score 0):

In your case

```
DISK_ARG_PRIMARY=$(echo "${DISK_ARG}" | cut -d: -f1)
DISK_ARG_SECONDARY=$(echo "${DISK_ARG}" | cut -d: -f2)
```

could be replaced with

```
DISK_ARG_PRIMARY=${DISK_ARG%:*}  # remove :* suffix
DISK_ARG_SECONDARY=${DISK_ARG#*:}  # remove *: prefix
```

to avoid subshell pipe and cut

also add `-w` option to grep to avoid to match substrings for example 5 will not match 51.

```
DISK_ARG_PRIMARY="10 20" 
DISK_ARG_SECONDARY="5 5"
```

To have

```
grep -Ew '(10|20):(5|5)'

grep -Ew "($(set -- $DISK_ARG_PRIMARY;IFS=\|;echo "$*")):($(set -- $DISK_ARG_SECONDARY;IFS=\|;echo "$*"))"
```